# Mostrar datos de MySQL a partir de de un campo de formulario en html con php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo conocimientos básicos de `html`. Me gustaría saber como  mostrar datos de una tabla en `html` con `php` a partir de una consulta previa realizada a la misma tabla de la base de datos

Es decir si tengo una tabla llamada registros con los campos:

> id_registro, codEm, mes, etc.

Quiero que me muestre en un option los diferentes años almacenados y a partir de la selección me muestre todos mis datos en una tabla.

```
          <?php
                    $Sqlc="select * from registros";
          ?>
          <select name="year">
              <?php  while($arreglo=mysql_fetch_array($Sqlc)) { ?>
                                <option value= "<?php echo $Sqlc['CodigoEm'] ?>" > <?php echo $Sqlc['Year']  ?></option>

                            </select>

                   <?php } ?>
```

Como puedo hacerlo??

Comment: bienvenido, favor de leer [ask], es necesario no solo exponer lo que quieres hacer sino además que llevas hecho

Comment: Aquí tienes material para que dejes el nivel básico: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/htmlya/html5/ - http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/phpya/ - http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/ajaxya/ - http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mysqlya/

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias por el material.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás buscando algo así:

```
<?php
    $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
    $rs=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM registros;");
    $txt='<form method="post">';
    $txt.='<select name="year">';
    while($r=$rs->fetch_assoc())
        $txt.='<option value= "'.$r['codEm'].'" >'.$r['mes'].'</option>';
    $txt.='</select>';
    $txt.='<button>Enviar</button>';
    $txt.='</form>';
    if(isset($_POST['year']))
        $txt.='<table border><tr><td>'.$_POST['year'].'</td></tr></table>';
    echo $txt;
?>
```

Adjunto también la base de datos en MySQL por si alguien quiere hacer algún retoque:

```
CREATE TABLE registros(
  id_registro int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  codEm varchar(31),
  mes varchar(31),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_registro)  
  );
INSERT INTO registros (codEm, mes) VALUES
  ('ene','Enero'),
  ('feb','Febrero'),
  ('mar','Marzo');
```

Comment: Gracias @David, Disculpa y si deseo tomar el valor del `select` y a partir de este mostrar datos en una tabla con el método POST.

Comment: Ok, hecho: he modificado la respuesta con lo que me pides. Recuerda votar y, si procede, dar ok a la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Releyendo tu pregunta, acabo de darme cuenta de que en la tabla igual no quieres el mes que seleccionas, sino el listado de meses completo y que, a lo mejor, te marque el mes seleccionado, ¿podría ser? Modifica tu pregunta para dejarlo claro y así lo dejamos bien documentado